# Remote debug with gdbServer

Tags: linux

1) I start GDB on remote machine by gdb myAppName

2) Then i give run -p portNumber

3) Then i run java application which connect with it on above mentioned port.

Now when i am trying to remote debug via gdbserver then the scenario is

1) I run gdb server on remote machine
    gdbserver host:port  path to application

Now when i try to connect my java client application to the gdbserver port .It will not be able to connect.

So i am searching of alternative of run -p command of gdb in gdb server

What i was trying was remote debugging of C code via eclipse CDT

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

gdbserver can be started attached to a pid on some systems according to the docs using the following syntax which is different than the normal invocation

> gdbserver *hostname* : *port* --attach *pid*

or gdb can be started with a program that is subsequently started by the remote machine

> gdbserver *hostname* : *port*  *program*

and then you can attach to it from another remote gdb using

> (gdb) target remote *hostname*: *port*

Eclipse would probably do the same thing so long at the remote gdbserver is invoked as above

and then start the remote program using a different port

> (gdb) run -p *someotherport*

This 2nd invocation, from your comments above, I assume you have created some flag to your program that allows it to bind to *someotherport*

Comment: But I do (gdb) run -p1034 where -p represent port.This cant be done in gdbserver.As it only associated with pid not port(it run on port)

Comment: If I understand your problem now.  gdbserver needs a communication port and your remote program also needs a port.  This is fine simply pick different ports.